# CSS Transition Running Backwards

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, transition

Alright, so I'm fairly new to website design and I'm having a problem with a transition on my website. http://www.artbymarissa.com/test

As you can see when you scroll down the navbar shrinks to half of it's size. It's supposed to growing from half it's size to full size but I can't find a solution. I feel like it's easy to fix but my brain is just not working at the second. Any help is appreciated!

HTML:

```
<header class="navbar" style="top: -1%; left: -1%;">
  <center><img src="http://files.enjin.com/1141108/05094af5e642a261732c8bcf78140f66c9602ad9da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd807098cf0696e.png" alt="" width="360" height="88" /></center>
</header>
<br />
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href="/homepage">Home</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href="/shop">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="reviews">Reviews</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href="/giveaway">Giveaways</a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://artbymarissa.buycraft.net/category/607213">Packages</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My code for the transition:

```
.scrolled {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  opacity: 95%;
  z-index: 999;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px #000000;
  transform: scale(.9); /* 1/10 of the original size */
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
.scrolled.opened {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sticky_top = $('.navigation').offset().top;
    $('.navigation').after('<div class="sticky_spacer" style="height: ' + $('.navigation').height() + 'px; display: none;"></div>');
    $('.sticky_spacer').css('transition', $('.navigation').css('transition'));
    function toggleSticky() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= sticky_top) {
            $('.navigation').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
            $('.sticky_spacer').show();
            $('.navigation').addClass('scrolled');
        }else {
            $('.navigation').css('position'  , 'relative').css('top', 'auto');
            $('.sticky_spacer').hide();
            $('.navigation').removeClass('scrolled');
        }
    }
    toggleSticky();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        toggleSticky();
    });
});
```

Comment: could you please create a DEMO for this?

Comment: Post your HTML also. And if possible create Snippet

Comment: Is that better? I didn't add the whole CSS since there was quite a bit of it but I can if you need it.
My website is Enjin.com based also, so if that may be part of the problem let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've went to your site and did some debugging from the developer console. And it seems like the problem causing it to shrink back down to half the size is

`scale(.9);`

Changing it to scale(1) or removing it altogether fixes the issue but also loses the animation. You can try other methods of making it full width instead of relying on scale.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how else I can do this?

Comment: I would recommend CSS transitions, but you would need to make your default navigation (without .scrolled) less than 100% so that the transition would work. I tried it and it worked but there was a slight problem. The nav bar would appear to jump to the left of the screen and then proceed to grow in width. That is probably caused by left:0;